# In Tomcat6.0 "The requested resource () is not available." occurred

Tags: jakarta-ee, tomcat, servlets, tomcat6

Yesterday I encountered one problem when programming with java servlet on remote server.

Our assignment is to build a simple shopping cart and user can add items by typing the name and clicking "submit", then servlet will be invoked and show the items purchased.

After I coded it, the server tells me error with "The requested resource () is not available." every time. I searched and tried all methods I could find but still not work.

Here are the codes:

HTML(/~usr/public_html/market.html)

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Online Shopping</title>
</head>

<body>
<h1>Online Shopping</h1>
Welcome to the online market!<br>
<br>
Please input the item you want to buy:<br>
<form action="http://localhost:8080/~usr/cart" method="get">
<input type="text" name="item"><br>
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>

</body>

</html>
```

web.xml(/~usr/public_html/WEB-INF/web.xml)

```
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee
http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
version="2.5">
<servlet>
<servlet-name>cart</servlet-name>
<servlet-class>cart</servlet-class>

<servlet-mapping>
<servlet-name>cart</servlet-name>
<url-pattern>/cart</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

Java Code(compiled and put it to /~usr/public_html/WEB-INF/classes/cart.class)

```
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpSession;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;


public class cart extends HttpServlet
{   
    public void doGet (HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse res) throws ServletException, IOException
    {
        res.setContentType("text/html");
        PrintWriter out = res.getWriter();

        HttpSession session = req.getSession(true);

        //get the previous number of items in cart. If none, creat it and initialize to zero
        Integer count = (Integer)session.getAttribute("count");
        if(count == null)
            count = new Integer(0);

        //declare a string reference to get the new added item, if it's null, don't add it
        String[] item_name;

        item_name = req.getParameterValues("item");
        if(item_name != null)
        {           
            count ++;
            session.setAttribute("count",count);    
            session.setAttribute("items"+count,item_name[0]);
        }

            out.println("<html>");
            out.println("<head>");
            out.println("<title>Items in Shopping Cart</title>");  
            out.println("</head>");
            out.println("<body>");
            out.println("New item successfully added to shopping cart.<br>");
            out.println("Your cart contains X items.<br><br>");
            out.println("<center><h1>The items you purchased:</h1>");

            for(int i=1; i<=count; i++)
                {
                    String goods = (String)session.getAttribute("items"+i);
                    out.println("Item #"+i+": "+goods+"<br>");
                }


            out.println("</center></body>");
            out.println("</html>");

            out.close();
    }



}
```

Tomcat and server are configured beforehand by professor and I just followed the rules where to put these files and so on.

Comment: What's the name of your WAR? By default it would be accessed at http://hostname:port/war/servlet  - all I know at this point is that `servlet` is `/cart`. I doubt very much that your WAR is called `~usr.war` but I could be wrong.

Comment: Actually ~usr/ is replaced by my user name in the server. This server is shared also by other classmates, so I can only access my own user folder. I don't know what's you called "war", because the tomcat has been set up and what we should do is to follow the rules to create folder with certain name and put correct stuff into correct folder. My classmate has run it successfully. I tried to modify my code into his style but still doesn't work.

Comment: The file structure has been added as comment to commit's answer

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to full path in action, replace below

```
<form action="http://localhost:8080/~usr/cart" method="get">
```

with following

```
<form action="cart" method="get">
```

Comment: try with `action="/cart"`

Comment: It is difficult to say without seeing your project structure, can you please see your detail file explorer and web.xml.

Comment: In folder /public_html there are market.html and another folder "WEB-INF". In /public_html/WEB-INF/ there are web.xml which was mentioned in the question and another folder "classes". In /public_html/WEB-INF/classes/ there is cart.class. That's all.

Answer (score 0):

Is that project deployed properly? Could you please check the server log? And Check whether the war has been extracted into webapps folder.